# Problema con prueba unitaria MSTest a un controlador con inyeccion de dependencia IDataProtector

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pruebas-unitarias, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Quiero realizar una prueba unitaria a la acción de crear de un controlador que tiene por inyección de dependencias un objeto IDataProtector. El error reside en que el objeto IDataProtector permanece null en dicha prueba (System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'protector')).

El código de la acción del controlador es el siguiente:

```
public class FiliacionesController : ControllerBase
{
    // Propiedades
    private readonly IRepositorioIncidencias _incidenciaService;
    private readonly IDataProtector _protector;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    // Constructor
    public FiliacionesController(IRepositorioIncidencias incidenciaService, IDataProtectionProvider protectionProvider, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _incidenciaService = incidenciaService; 
        _protector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("xxxxxxxxx"); 
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    // Método
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] FiliacionDTO_Post _filiacion)
    {
        // Encriptación de campos de la filiación            
        var domicilioCript = "";
        var telefonoCript = "";
        var nombreCript = _protector.Protect(_filiacion.Nombre);           
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_filiacion.Direccion))
        {
            domicilioCript = _protector.Protect(_filiacion.Direccion);
        }
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_filiacion.Telefono))
        {
            telefonoCript = _protector.Protect(_filiacion.Telefono);
        }     

        // actualizamos los campos con los datos encriptados
        _filiacion.Nombre = nombreCript;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(domicilioCript))
        {
            _filiacion.Direccion = domicilioCript;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(telefonoCript))
        {
            _filiacion.Telefono = telefonoCript;
        }

        var filiacion = _mapper.Map<Filiacion>(_filiacion);

        // Insertamos filiación
        var resultado = await _incidenciaService.AddFiliacion(filiacion);
        if (resultado)
        {
            return new CreatedAtRouteResult("ObtenerFiliacion", new { id = filiacion.Id_Filiacion }, filiacion);
        }
        else
        {                    
            return BadRequest();
        }   
    }
```

}

El código de la prueba unitaria es el siguiente:

```
[TestClass]
    public class SeguridadControllersTest
    {
        // inyeccion de dependencias
        Mock<IRepositorioIncidencias> mock;            
        Mock<IDataProtectionProvider> protectionProvider;
        MapperConfiguration mockMapper;

        // Constructor
        public SeguridadControllersTest()
        {
            this.mock = new Mock<IRepositorioIncidencias>();
            this.protector = new Mock<IDataProtector>();
            this.protectionProvider = new Mock<IDataProtectionProvider>();
            this.mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.AddProfile(new IncidenciasMappingProfile());
            });
        }

        // Método
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Post_CrearFiliacion_OK()
        {
            #region Arrange                            

            var filiacionDTO = new FiliacionDTO_Post()
            {
                Nombre = "Nombre Filiacion",
                Dni = "12345678A",
                Pasaporte = null,
                Fecha_nac = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/1985"),
                Lugar_nac = "Lugar nacimiento",
                Direccion = "Direccion",
                Poblacion = "Población",
                Provincia = "Provincia",
                Pais = "Pais",
                Observaciones = null,
                Telefono = "666123123"
            };
            mock.Setup(x => x.AddFiliacion(It.IsAny<Filiacion>())).ReturnsAsync(true);            
            var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();            
            var controladorFiliaciones = new FiliacionesController(mock.Object, protectionProvider.Object, mapper);
            #endregion

            #region Act

            var resultado = await controladorFiliaciones.Post(filiacionDTO);
            #endregion

            #region Assert

            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(resultado, typeof(CreatedAtRouteResult));
            mock.Verify(x => x.AddFiliacion(It.IsAny<Filiacion>()));
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

La línea del código que lanza la excepción está en el controlador (var nombreCript = _protector.Protect(_filiacion.Nombre);) y es debido a que "_protector" permanece null. Haciendo el seguimiento en la depuración observo como los argumentos del constructor del controlador reciben los valores correctamente, el problema es que en el constructor _protector no se iguala a la configuración del objeto IDataProviderProtection.

No veo donde estoy cometiendo el error. Si podéis ayudarme...

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que te falta configurar el método `CreateProtector`.

```
protectionProvider.Setup(x => x.CreateProtector(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() =>
    {
         // Lógica aquí...
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesse R. Jose. Mi problema era que no contruía el objeto IDataProtector en la configuración del objeto IDataProtectionProvider. Lo he solucionado de esta forma: protectionProvider.Setup(x => x.CreateProtector("XXXXXXX")).Returns(_protector.Object); donde _protector.Object el el objeto IDataProtector. De esta forma, en el contructor este mismo objeto no permanece null.

Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No hay de que...